# How to make popup.html links open in tab?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that has some links in it. Currently when clicked the links do nothing, i would like to make them open in a new tab when clicked. Is this possible?

Comment: There are also some good answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915845/chrome-extension-open-a-link-from-popup-html-in-a-new-tab

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Add `target="_blank"` to links.

Another way is to attach link opening javascript code to mousedown event on a link.

You can also use `base` tag to make all links open with `target="_blank"`:

```html
<head>
    <base target="_blank">
</head>
```

Comment: +1. Make sure to specify `http://` (not just www.) in the links or they will open relative to the extension.

Comment: ok, thing is i was getting javascript from an external src so to my knowledge i can't edit it.

Comment: @user556396 so you can't edit html and can't edit javascript? Is this inside iframe or something?

Comment: no i used: <script src="http://example.com/example.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and this was my approach:

1. Create the popup.html with link (and the links are not working when clicked as Chrome block them).
2. Create popup.js and link it in the page: `<script src="popup.js" ></script>`
3. Add the following code to popup.js:

   ```
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
       var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
       for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
           (function () {
               var ln = links[i];
               var location = ln.href;
               ln.onclick = function () {
                   chrome.tabs.create({active: true, url: location});
               };
           })();
       }
   });
   ```

That's all, links should work after that.

Comment: You've forgotten to close over variable `i` in the closure. Further, `chrome.tabs.create` doesn't require any permissions.

Comment: I do not need to close over i, only ln and location are enough. You are right about permission, modified my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Re: is there another way

```
chrome.tabs.create( { url: "http://www.ajaxian.com"} );
```

See http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html