# Chrome extension; open a link from popup.html in a new tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm doing a Chrome extension and I got helped in this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874907/chrome-extension-used-to-refresh-pages).

My problem now is how to open a new tab of chrome that has as URL the link I clicked in the `popup.html`. I tried to do like someone suggested in their answers in other similar question like setting `<a>`'s attribute `target` to `_blank` but the only result is that chrome does open a new tab but in the new tab is my popup.html.

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make popup.html links open in tab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549869/how-to-make-popup-html-links-open-in-tab)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You should use [chrome.tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html) module to manually open the desired link in a new tab. Try using this jQuery snippet in your popup.html:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('body').on('click', 'a', function(){
     chrome.tabs.create({url: $(this).attr('href')});
     return false;
   });
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't that a's attribute I put as URL 'href'. Bytheway it doesn't work in both cases. It opens me a tab with this url: chrome-extension://ceapmkdonphjngfdcjcoahdmkenpbgpn/?action=read&idnotizia=71189

Comment: You are right about 'href', sorry for that - i fixed my answer. You need to supply full url in href if you want it to open. Currently you have links like this `<a href='?action=read&idnotizia=71189'>` change them to full URLs `<a href='http://yoursite.com?action=read&idnotizia=71189'>`.

Comment: I thought it was a problem with my extension. I concatenated the domain name to the string and now works perfectly.

Comment: Note this only works for links that exist in the document at load time, and is also very inefficient. To catch ALL link clicks efficiently, no matter when the link appeared, use $('body').on('click', 'a', function ()...

Answer (score 47):

See my comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/17732609/1340178

---

I had the same issue and this was my approach:

1. Create the popup.html with link (and the links are not working when clicked as Chrome block them).
2. Create popup.js and link it in the page: `<script src="popup.js" ></script>`
3. Add the following code to popup.js:

   ```
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
       var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
       for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
           (function () {
               var ln = links[i];
               var location = ln.href;
               ln.onclick = function () {
                   chrome.tabs.create({active: true, url: location});
               };
           })();
       }
   });
   ```

That's all, links should work after that.

Comment: I use the same javascript for options.html and popup.html, this code solves the problem for popup.html but also causes trouble for options.html when it opens two tabs for the same link (because options.html doesn't need that fix), but I don't want to use separate js files, do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: seems I found a solution to check if page is popup or options: `if (chrome.extension.getViews({ type: "popup" }).length > 0) { // execute your code }`

Comment: also we need this only for Google Chrome and Opera, but we should not add this code in Firefox extensions (WebExtensions) cause in Firefox it works fine without any fix, if you add it, it will open two tabs with Firefox extension

Answer (score 23):

If you don't want to use JQuery, insert this into your popup.js and it will make all your links open in a new tab when clicked

Remember to declarer the "tabs" permission in the manifest.json

```
window.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  if(e.target.href!==undefined){
    chrome.tabs.create({url:e.target.href})
  }
})
```

Comment: I'd suggest to use the "activeTab" permission instead: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab

Answer (score 15):

The other answers work.  For completeness, another way is to [just add](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4549879/32453) `target="_blank"`

Or if you have want to "manually" add particular links, here's a way (based on the other answers already here):

popup.html

```html
<a id="index_link">My text</a>.
```

popup.js

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
   var y = document.getElementById("index_link");
   y.addEventListener("click", openIndex);
});

function openIndex() {
   chrome.tabs.create({active: true, url: "http://my_url"});
}
```

Comment: whoah this needs more attention.. :)

Comment: Can confirm that `target="_blank"` behaves as expected on both Firefox (version 72) and Chrome (version 79).

Answer (score 2):

A bit more concise and actual syntax in 2020:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const links = document.querySelectorAll("a");

  links.forEach(link => {
    const location = link.getAttribute('href');
    link.addEventListener('click', () => chrome.tabs.create({active: true, url: location}));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit more concise version in modern JS:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  for (const anchor of document.getElementsByTagName('a')) {
    anchor.onclick = () => {
      chrome.tabs.create({active: true, url: anchor.href});
    };
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Looked like Konrad's solution would worked, but it opened multiple tabs at once. This happened only after first extension install. So I changed it to

```
if (e.target.classList.contains("a-link")) {
    chrome.tabs.create({url: $(e.target).attr('href')});
    return false;
}
```

and all is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Send tab url to share blog in new tab:

```
// popup.js
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function(tabs){        
    var url = tabs[0].url;
    var title = tabs[0].title;
    document.getElementById('linkQZone').onclick = function () {
        var url1 = 'https://sns.qzone.qq.com/cgi-bin/qzshare/cgi_qzshare_onekey?url=' + url + '&title=' + title + '&desc=&summary=&site=';
        chrome.tabs.create({active: true, url: url1});
    };

    document.getElementById('linkQQ').onclick = function () {
        var url1 = 'https://connect.qq.com/widget/shareqq/index.html?url=' + url + '&title=' + title + '&desc=&summary=&site=';
        chrome.tabs.create({active: true, url: url1});
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

open with ctrl-click or middle-click

```
$('body').on('click auxclick', 'a', e => {
    if (e.ctrlKey || e.button == 1) {
        e.preventDefault();
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: e.currentTarget.href, selected: false});
    }
});
```