# How would I go about this? (Chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm new to creating extensions, and I'm trying to become more comfortable with them.  Basically, I'm trying to create a simple extension that does the following:

1. Open a new window (achieved).
2. Have the ability to 'click' a button from the extension (not achieved).

I'm not sure how to approach having the extension click the button in a new window.  How can I approach this? This is what I have right now:

**`popup.html`**

```
<html>
        <body>
                <input type="button" id="the_button" value="My button"></input>
        </body>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
</html>
```

**`popup.js`**

```
document.getElementById("the_button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var win = window.open("http://www.roblox.com", "roblox", 400, 400)
    //Now what can I do to externally click buttons?
})
```

**`manifest.json`**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test",
  "description": "Test Extension",
  "version": "1.0",

  "icons": { 
    "48": "icon.png"
   },

  "permissions": [
    "http://*/*", 
    "https://*/*"
  ],

  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://*/*", "http://*/*"],
    "js": ["jquery.js", "popup.js"]
  }],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "This is a test",
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question title to be more descriptive (and no need for duplicating tags in there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE**: since January 2021, use [Manifest V3](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/) with [`chrome.scripting.executeScript()`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#method-executeScript) and the `scripting` permission and move `"*://*/*"` to `host_permissions` instead of using the deprecated `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` with the `tabs` permission.

---

First of all, you're making a mistake using the `</input>` closing tag: **`<input>` tags don't need to be closed!** So change your `popup.html` into this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="the_button" value="My button">
    </body>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</html>
```

---

*Now, getting to the real question:*

You need to create a new tab, then inject a content script into the page. **Here is a quick solution:**

1. Add the `tabs` permission to your `manifest.json`:

   ```
   ...
   "permissions": [
       "*://*/*", // this will match both http and https :)
       "tabs"
   ],
   ...
   ```

   **Remove the `popup.js` content script from the manifest**, that's useless! You don't need it.

   ```
   ...
   "content_scripts": [{                         // remove!
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "http://*/*"], // remove!
        "js": ["jquery.js", "popup.js"]          // remove!
    }],                                          // remove!
   ...
   ```

   **WARNING**: When I say **remove** I mean trurly remove that lines from your `manifest.json`, do not use comments (`//`) and do not copy and paste my code over your code, just **delete** that four lines.
2. Now, in your `popup.js` you can inject a content script inside your page when you open the tab, like this:

   ```
   document.getElementById("the_button").addEventListener("click", function() {
       chrome.tabs.open({url:"http://www.roblox.com", active:"true"}, function(tab) {
           chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file:"click_the_button.js", run_at: "document_end"});
           // here is where you inject the content script ^^
       }
   });
   ```
3. This will create a new tab and inject inside it the script `click_the_button.js`, the one you will use to click the button inside the page (when it's loaded), whose code would be:

   ```
   var thing = $("a#roblox-confirm-btn");
   thing.click();
   ```

**NOTE:** if you want to use jQuery in your `click_the_button.js` script, you can as well inject it in the tab before it:

```
document.getElementById("the_button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    chrome.tabs.open({url:"http://www.roblox.com", active:"true"}, function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file:"jQuery.js", run_at: "document_start"});
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file:"click_the_button.js", run_at: "document_end"});
    }
});
```

---

**Resources you may find useful:**

- [`chrome.tabs.create` method](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create)
- [`chrome.tabs.executeScript` method](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript)

Comment: Word of warning: `// comments` in .json files are a syntax error!

Comment: Yes I know, thanks, those comments are just to highlight the part of code to remove from the `messages.json` file

Comment: People tend to just copy code. Explain it outside the code block

Answer (score -1):

You need tabs permission.
I had the same problem before.
The answer is here:

[Chrome extension; open a link from popup.html in a new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915845/chrome-extension-open-a-link-from-popup-html-in-a-new-tab)