# How do I open a URL in a new tab from within a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to use an image as a button (setting.png), and onclick open a URL in a new tab.

My popup.html:

```
    <html>
  <head>

    <style>
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href = "http://google.com" id="link"><img src="setting.png" width="30px" height="auto"></a>
    <script src ="javascript.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "",
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.5",
  "offline_enabled": true,
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "icons": { "16": "icon16.png",
              "32": "icon32.png",
           "48": "icon48.png",
           "64": "icon64.png",
          "128": "icon128.png" },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",
    "storage",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

javascipt.js:

```
window.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  if(e.target.href!==undefined){
    chrome.tabs.create({url:e.target.href})
  }
})
```

So when I click on the image I want to open the URL in a new tab. Thanks!

Comment: Please use search next time.

Comment: Sorry @xan but this doesn't suit my needs.

Comment: It explicitly does. You don't use jQuery so the accepted answer does not apply, but there are 2 non-jQuery answers there.

Comment: And of course it's possible that it doesn't suit your needs in a copy&paste way, but then you need to specify your needs more clearly, and show _how_ you tried to apply that answer and failed.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I've updated my code. I tried using http://stackoverflow.com/a/26216955/5586484. But it doesn't seem to work. Could you please tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You have to understand what you're using. That particular answer (and other answers as well) relies on the `href` attribute. You don't have it on your link.

Comment: "<a href = "http://google.com" id="link"><img.." this, correct? I added the href later. Am I still doing it wrong?

Comment: Comments break formatting, but make sure you add `http://` or `https://` to your links - `chrome.tabs` won't work without a full URL.

Comment: I have that's just the SO comments, please see the code. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, now that the question is different (fixing a particular implementation), I'm removing the duplicate. Just to make sure - did you properly reload the extension after changes?

Comment: Yes I did. When I hover over the image, currently it only acts like an image and it's not clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Chrome sets the innermost clicked element in `event.target` which is the image.
2. There's no need for a `click` handler, just use `target="_blank"` attribute for the link:

```
<a href="http://google.com" id="link" target="_blank">
```

P.S. In case of problems **always use the [debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging)** to see what's actually happening (set a breakpoint inside the click handler, click the link, examine the parameters and so on).

Comment: Thank you for you answer @wOxxOm! Alright, so correct me if I'm wrong, I can remove the click handler (i.e. all the JS)? I've used your code, but it still isn't working..

Comment: 1. `There's no need for a click handler` as you can see in the answer 2. It works, I've just tested it here

Comment: Either post the exact code you're using or upload the entire extension somewhere, e.g. http://tinyupload.com/

Comment: it is adding chrome-extention id before the URL

Comment: @NikhilKulkarni, no, it does not. Make sure your URL specified in `href` has a protocol like shown in the answer.