# Open Chrome extension link within popup

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, href

I am trying to create sub menus in a very simple Chrome extension within `popup.html`. I've been successful at creating links to open pages in a new tab using html. For instance:

```
<a class="two" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore">
  <img width="16" height="16" src="webstore.png" />Chrome Web Store
</a>
```

I added the following event listener to `popup.js` to get this to work:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    (function () {
      var ln = links[i];
      var location = ln.href;
      ln.onclick = function () {
        chrome.tabs.create({active: true, url: location});
      };
    })();
  }
});
```

In order to minimize the number of links in `popup.html`, I would like to create a submenu system, where a user clicks on a link to open a new html document in the popup.

```
<a class="two" href="submenu.html">
  <img width="16" height="16" src="submenu.png" />Submenu
</a>
```

The popup will contain more links like the one to the Chrome Webstore in the first example. Of course, this opens `submenu.html` in a new tab, not within the Chrome extension popup. Is there an easy way to open a link within the popup, rather than in a new tab?

Thank you.

Comment: `<a class="two" href="submenu.html">` should work, but it'll replace the current popup document and all its scripts of course.

Comment: I guess the question is more like: How can i get it to ignore the previous event listener. If I remove it completely, the links I want to open in a new tab will not work. I imagine I would have to set `id="myLink"` within for `<a>` but I'm not sure if that is the right approach.

Comment: Simply add `target="_blank"` to the external links and remove the listener code altogether.

Comment: Thank you. I was having the same problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915845/chrome-extension-open-a-link-from-popup-html-in-a-new-tab). I'm going to see if I can get it to only apply to links I want to open in a new tab and not to the `submenu.html` link.

Comment: Why are you using a separate HTML file for your sub-menu?

Answer (score 0):

I think I answered my own question:

1. First add apply EventListener only when `name="newtab"`

   ```
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
       var links = document.getElementsByName("newtab");
       for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
           (function () {
               var ln = links[i];
               var location = ln.href;
               ln.onclick = function () {
                   chrome.tabs.create({active: true, url: location});
               };
           })();
       }
   });`
   ```
2. Add `name="newtab"` to each `<a>` where you want to open in a new tab.
3. For all other links, proceed normally; they will open in the popup.